# Scheme design in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We provide games for our customers. Games id's can be of two types:

1. our company gameId
2. customer gameId (aka gameCode)

customer can choose to use his own gameCode. to enable this they must map between our gameId to their gameCode (a separate process).

our firebase database works in respective to our company gameId's only that means when our app is loading the customers who using gameCode gotta be mapped into gameIds so our app will be able to work with it

we came up with this scheme but we are not sure about it

we will have long dictionary (around customer 4000 game codes) and it will map into gameIds. When customer using gameIds or gameCodes will just use this route in firebase and see if exists and that how the mapping will work

```
root/games/<gameCode>
{
  <gameCode>:<gameId>
}

and

root/games/<gameId>
{
  <gameId>:<gameId>
}
```

we can do something else but we afraid it will cost query performances:

Now when customer comes with gameId we will iterate the games sub-tree (which is alot smaller then then game codes ~ around 400 games) and look for the given gameCode if found it we got the mapping

```
root/games/<gameId> {    
   "gameCodes":{
        gameCode1:true,
        gameCode2:true 
   }, 
root/games/<gameId> {    
    "gameCodes":{
        gameCode3:true,
        gameCode4:true 
    }
```

thoughts?

Comment: why not to design the db and access with a `key -> value` context, instead of traversing trees, it's **alot** cheaper

Comment: @shahaf can you add an example

Comment: I'd definitely recommend against that second structure, as you'd have to search all game IDs to find a specific code. Your first structure looks much more in line with what you're trying to accomplish in this use-case. What's your concern with the first structure?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my concern is that ill need to execute lots of 'isExists()' method on initialization on very very big list as those game-codes going to get bigger and bigger (e.g can get into thousands keys)

Comment: If the user enters a single code, that's a single existence check isn't it? If you also need the inverse lookup, I'd add an additional inverted index. You'd then keep the two in sync with a multi-location update from your code and enforce that with security rules..